# How to override bootstrap cdn css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am trying to override **bootstrap success message**. I tried to do it in my CSS page , but its showing me 2 styles now one above the each other.

How can I fix it ?

**My code :**

```
#sm-box { 
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    margin: 0! important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    background-color: #008fd8 !important;
}
```

Comment: Try !important in you css

Comment: Can you show the code you tried? Also, can you clarify what you mean when you say it's showing 2 styles now?

Comment: I updated my question. I tried !important, it did not help.Its showing me the original success message above the one from my CSS

Comment: Are you placing your custom CSS AFTER the Bootstrap CSS CDN?

Comment: Please do some research about CSS priority. There are many things about this online.

Answer (score 0):

you can give high priority to your CSS

link your CSS from the bottom

Comment: My CSS is the bottom , it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
!important
```

in you front of your  css rules

Comment: In many cases, `!important` is trying to hammer something into shape rather than gracefully doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.message-block #sm-box { 
    border-radius: 0px ;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px ;
    background-color:#008fd8 ;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<dib class="message-block">
<div id="sm-box"> 
message 
</div>
<div>
```

I think is it solution